# map of map get outer map based on inner map value

Tags: java, java-8

How do I write below code using Java8?

```
for (Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
  Map<String, Object> value = entry.getValue();
  if (value.get(Constants.USER_TRAN_ID).equals(stsTxn.getSeedTrade().getTransactionId())) {
    closedTaxLotByTxnId = value;
    break;
  }
}
```

I am clueless after this

```
data.values().stream().map(e -> e.get(Constants.USER_TRAN_ID)).filter(txnId -> txnId.equals(stsTxn.getSeedTrade().getTransactionId()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `map`. Just use `filter` with your criteria, and `findFirst` as terminal operation:

```
Optional<Map<String, Object>>
    value = data.values()
                .stream()
                .filter(m -> m.get(Constants.USER_TRAN_ID).equals(stsTxn.getSeedTrade().getTransactionId()))
                .findFirst();
```

If you want a default value (such as null) when no match is found, use:

```
Map<String, Object> closedTaxLotByTxnId =
           data.values()
               .stream()
               .filter(m -> m.get(Constants.USER_TRAN_ID).equals(stsTxn.getSeedTrade().getTransactionId()))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(null);
```

Comment: @JigarNaik `...findFirst()` returns an `Optional<Map<String, Object>>`, so `...findFirst().orElse(something)` will return a value whose type is `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: One more question why I can't directly return as added in original question?

Comment: @JigarNaik what's the return type of the method and what error are you getting?

Comment: understood, one of the bracket was missing.